# Gmail.js synchronous before sendMessage

Tags: javascript

I am using the Gmail.js library's `gmail.observe.before("send_message", function(){...});` function. In this I have added an event listener that listens for a message that contains the new body that is to be included in the email body. However, the message is sent first and the new string is received later, how would I make the rest of the code wait until the listener gets the new string?

```
gmail.observe.before('send_message', function(url, body, data, xhr) {

console.log('sent the message');

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {

        console.log(event.data.text);
        var newstring = (event.data.text);
        console.log(newstring);

        var oldCmml = xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml;

        var body_params = xhr.xhrParams.body_params;

        if (newstring.length > oldCmml) {
            xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml = newstring.length;
        } else {
            while (newstring.length < oldCmml) {
                newstring += ' ';
            }
            xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml = newstring.length;
        }

        body_params.body = newstring;

        }

    });
    console.log("sent");
});
```

"Sent" is logged before the new string is logged in the console. I need the new string logged before the "sent". I would deeply appreciate any help on this matter

Comment: Why you're registering a new event handler `message` instead of directly change the params in `xhr`?

Comment: because i need them from an external source. That's why i added the event listener.